# Sum up ArrayList<Double> via Java Stream

Tags: double, java-8, java-stream

Im trying to Figure out how to Sum up all the elements of an 'ArrayList'.

Ive tried already:

```
 double totalevent = myList.stream().mapToDouble(f -> f).sum();
```

while `myList` is a `ArrayList<Double>`.

is there a way to do it without the useless `mapToDouble` function?

Comment: I noticed that the stream version is much slower than the traditional for-loop. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The `mapToDouble` call is not useless: it performs an implicit unboxing. Actually it's the same as

```
double totalevent = myList.stream().mapToDouble(f -> f.doubleValue()).sum();
```

Or

```
double totalevent = myList.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum();
```

Alternatively you can use [`summingDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-) collector, but it's not a big difference:

```
double totalevent = myList.stream().collect(summingDouble(f -> f));
```

In my `StreamEx` library you can construct a `DoubleStream` directly from `Collection<Double>`:

```
double totalevent = DoubleStreamEx.of(myList).sum();
```

However internally it [also uses](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/blob/248b1ef252dec7b2c529bef7886382321ccbfd4c/src/main/java/javax/util/streamex/DoubleStreamEx.java#L1139) `mapToDouble`.

Comment: Would it be better in performance to use a normal for each loop in order to some the double values up, instead of each of those possibilities?

Comment: @Joel, that depends on what do you want to achieve. You may notice that `for(Double val: myList) sum+=val;` may produce different result, because of limited precision of `double` type. The stream solutions implement Kahan summation algorithm which does the good job in eliminating rounding errors. Of course it's slower, but the result is more correct especially if you have the numbers of different magnitude. If you don't care about this, feel free to use the normal loop.

Comment: @TagirValeev Why is the stream version slower?